# How should I make a nested parallel foreach loop in R within function?

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing, nested

```
coreBuffer = 1                            
cores0 <- detectCores() - coreBuffer
registerDoParallel(cores=cores0) 
cl.spec <- rep("localhost", cores0)
cl <- makeCluster(cl.spec, type="SOCK", outfile="") 
registerDoParallel(cl, cores=cores0)
clusterEvalQ(cl, .libPaths(.libPaths()))

foreach(i=1:2, .combine = list, .multicombine = TRUE, .packages = c("manyPackages"))%dopar%{
    if(i==1){a = manyThingsFunction(...)}
    if(i==2){a = oneThingFunction(...)}
    a
}

manyThingsFunction <- function(...){
    foreach(j=1:3, .combine = list, .multicombine = TRUE, .packages = c("manyPackages"))%dopar%{
        source(usedFunctionPath)
        b = moremanyThingsFunction(...)
        b
    }
}
```

Should I allocate workers within manyThingsFunction as I made it at the Main part?
If I make 5 workers at the main and I use 2 workers at the main foreach loop then they can use the left 3 workers within the workers?

Comment: First of all, you should carefully consider if you really want to nest parallelized loops. Usually, it is most efficient to only parallelize the outer loop. Then, you cannot (should not) nest two `%dopar%`, you need to use the nesting operator `%:%`. Read about it in the [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/foreach/vignettes/nested.html).

Comment: Thank you fro your answer.
However, As I tested it has worked as I want. I will make further tests at the future, because I used only 3 cores from 4.
(So, the inner foreach loop in the function use as many workers as it is possible (left).)

Results without paralelism: more then 1 hour and 1 hour = 2 hour
Results if only the inner loop paralelized: 1 hour and half hour = 1,5 hour
Results if both parallelized: 1 hour and 15 minutes = 1,25 hour